# Index was outside the bounds of the array confusion

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn two dimensional array and I wrote some basic code, but I am getting this exception. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[,] array = new int[2, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; i++)
        {
            array[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i, 0] + "---" + array[i, 1]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your inner `for`-loop. In the iterator section, you're incrementing the `i` variable, but it should be `j`. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```